# Can't find the error in this facebook wall jquery code

Tags: jquery, html

Here's a simple jquery and html  script to simulate the facebook wall, but it isn't working. Could someone help me out?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("form#submit_wall").submit(function () {

            var message_box = $('#message_box').attr('value');

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",

                data: "message_box=" + message_box,
                success: function () {
                    $("ul#wall").prepend("<li style="
                        display: none;
                        ">" + message_box + "</li>");
                    $("ul#wall li:first").fadeIn();
                }
            });
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="submit_wall">
        <label for="message_box">Type your experience :</label>
        <input type="text" id="message_box" />
        <button type="submit">Post it!</button>
    </form>
    <ul id="wall"></ul>
```

Comment: What is not working? Any error messages on the console?

Comment: No error messages.. When I click the submit button nothing happens.. the <ul> element stays the same..

Comment: first, there is a syntax error, it should be:  $("ul#wall").prepend("<li style='display: none;'>" + message_box +"</li>"); fuhrter more do you have a demopage to test the serverresponse?

Comment: stuff like this calls for basic debugging. Step by step walk through the code, test outputting variables, until you find the point at which things go wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your quotes are off.... also don't forget to set the `URL` you are sending the request to!
 ( `$.ajax({ url: ... , type: ...` ).

**Problem:**

```
$("ul#wall").prepend("<li style="display: none;">"+message_box+"</li>");
```

You need to pay attention to which quotes will be rendered as part of the string and which quotes denote the string boundaries.

**Solution:**

```
$("ul#wall").prepend('<li style="display: none;">' + message_box + '</li>');
```

Look at the difference in the syntax highlighting of these 2 code snippets.

### [Try it out with this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qkhqv/)

Comment: Hey.. Thanks for that :) The code is working perfectly in jsfiddle.. but not working here.. Im running WAMP on my localhost...

Comment: @Ram - Are you sure your jQuery source link is correct ( `jquery.js` not `/jquery.js` or `/jquery/jquery.js` or something else )? So is jQuery loading properly?

Comment: yes..ive tested it both with minified nd normal... still nt working :(

Comment: @Ram - To be clear, if you try a simple `$(function() { alert("jQuery is working!"; });` you do get the alert? ---------------- I assume your HTML is correct, unlike in your posted example (you don't have an open `html` or `head` tag and you don't have a close `body`, or `html` tags?

Comment: Hey! I get the alert when so jquery is working fine.. also yes.. the html posted here is incomplete.. What else cud it be! THis is driving me nuts!

Comment: @Ram - Strange - Do you use Firebug? Try debugging with that... Can you give a link to the page?

Comment: Hey Peter! Thanks so much for all your help! Caught the error with chrome developer tools.. There was a non unicode character in the script!

Answer (score 1):

You're not using the correct variable name.  You've named the variable `message_wall` but are attempting to use it as `message_box`.  You might also need to supply the url for the AJAX post.  It will use the page's url if not specified, but typically you'd pull it from the form's action as it is likely different.  I would also use `val()` to get the value from the input.

```
 $('form#submit_wall').submit( function() {
     var url = $(this).attr('action');
     var message_box = $('#message_box').val();
     $.ajax({
         url: url,
         type: 'POST',
         data: 'message_box=' + message_box,
         success: function() { ... }
     });
     return false;
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

`message_box` is undefined, you initialize `message_wall` ...

Comment: First post was edited, before it was : `var message_wall = ... ` ;)